# script in html doesn't work on generic controller from code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I used collapsible button with content `div` in my work.
The div opening/closing is controlled by the script in `html`.
I checked the functionality on a button and div that I added in the `html` and it works, but when I'm adding button and div from code behind it doesn't work.

The button and div from `html`:

```
<div id="class_picker" runat="server" style="height: 200px; min-width: 150px; overflow: hidden; overflow-y: scroll;">
    <button class="collapsible" type="button">Cardio training</button>
    <div class="content">
        <p>
           <u style="font: bold">Trainer:</u><asp:Label ID="trainer" runat="server" CssClass="card-text">Dolev Bastiker</asp:Label>
           <br />
           <u style="font: bold">Date:</u><asp:Label ID="date" runat="server" CssClass="card-text">22/06/19</asp:Label>
           <br />
           <u style="font: bold">Time:</u><asp:Label ID="time" runat="server" CssClass="card-text">18:00</asp:Label>
           <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Sign To Class" Style="float: right" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
        </p>
     </div>
  </div>
```

The generic button and div from code behind:

```
HtmlGenericControl newLesDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
HtmlGenericControl newLesButton = new HtmlGenericControl("button");
newLesButton.Attributes.Add("class", "collapsible");
newLesButton.Attributes.Add("type", "button");
newLesButton.InnerText = temp.getName() + " - " + temp.getTime();
HtmlGenericControl lesContentDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
lesContentDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "content");
HtmlContainerControl lesContentPara = (HtmlContainerControl)new HtmlGenericControl("p");
//HtmlGenericControl lesContentPara = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
HtmlGenericControl lesTrainer = new HtmlGenericControl("label");
HtmlGenericControl lesDate = new HtmlGenericControl("label");
HtmlGenericControl lesTime = new HtmlGenericControl("label");
HtmlGenericControl lesCapacity = new HtmlGenericControl("label");
HtmlGenericControl lesAssignButton = new HtmlGenericControl("button");
lesAssignButton.Attributes.Add("type", "button");
lesAssignButton.InnerText = "Sign to " + temp.getName() + " - " + temp.getTime();
lesAssignButton.Attributes.Add("onClick", "Assinment_Click");

lesTrainer.InnerText = temp.getTrainer();
lesCapacity.InnerText = temp.getParticipant() + "/" + temp.getMax_participant();
lesDate.InnerText = date;
lesTime.InnerText = temp.getTime();

lesContentPara.Controls.Add(lesTrainer);
lesContentPara.Controls.Add(lesCapacity);
lesContentPara.Controls.Add(lesTime);
lesContentPara.Controls.Add(lesCapacity);
lesContentPara.Controls.Add(lesAssignButton);

lesContentDiv.Controls.Add(lesContentPara);
newLesDiv.Controls.Add(newLesButton);
newLesDiv.Controls.Add(lesContentDiv);

class_picker.Controls.Add(newLesDiv);
```

The script in html:

```
<script>
        var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
            coll[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                var content = this.nextElementSibling;
                if (content.style.maxHeight) {
                    content.style.maxHeight = null;
                } else {
                    content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

The expected result is generic adding of buttons and divs from code behind with the same behavior of the button and the div from the html.

Answer (score 0):

What I got from your question is, that you are creating HTML from code behind and rendering it on the form, but you are not getting the expected behaviour of HTML controls or script.
To overcome this situation the script you have written should be converted into a function and the same function should be called from code behind after the HTML controls are rendered on the form.

Move your javascript code into a function

```
  <script>
function BindClickEvent(){
          var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
          var i;

          for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
              coll[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                  this.classList.toggle("active");
                  var content = this.nextElementSibling;
                  if (content.style.maxHeight) {
                      content.style.maxHeight = null;
                  } else {
                      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
                  }
              });
          }
        }
    </script>
```

You can use register client script block like

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction","BindClickEvent()",true);
```

Comment: Just a correction use Register client script block instead of Register startup script
  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "BindClickEvent();", true);